# Is there an equivalent of Mac OS X "open" command that can be called from C++/Objective-C code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, command-line

On Mac OS X there is a very useful "open" command which launches an application suitable for opened file type. Is there some C++/Objective-C function on Mac which does the same?

*Note: I know I could launch an "open" process. I'm just not sure if it's the best option.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is done by `NSWorkspace`. See [`-[NSWorkspace openFile:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIBGECG). All you have to do is

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"file.txt"]
```

If you want more fine-grained control (e.g. getting all applications which can open a given file,)
you use Launch Services. See the [document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html) and the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).